# Unable to run analysis on SonarQube 5.1

Tags: maven, sonarqube

When I run mvn sonar:sonar for my project I keep getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project prova: SonarQube 5.1 does not support Maven 3
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

SonarQube log (the one located in /opt/sonar/logs) is clear and doesn't show any error.

I suppose it's a configuration error but i can't figure out how to solve it.
I am running SonarQube 5.1 64bit, maven 3.1.1 and java1.8.0_45-b14 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

**[EDIT:]**
I've runned mvn -V sonar:sonar from my windows pc with maven 3.1.1 installed and got the same error:

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 17:22:2
2+0200)
Maven home: F:\DARKFOX\maven
Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building prova 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) @ prova ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset/
/EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<meta name="VERSION" content="">
<meta name="DATA" content="fwdnode2.registrar-servers.com (98.142.221.8)">
<link href=" " rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
<title></title>
</head>
<frameset rows='100%, *' frameborder=no framespacing=0 border=0>
<frame src="http://server1.darkfoxdev.com:9000/sonar/api/server/version" name=ma
inwindow frameborder=no framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></frame>
</frameset>
<noframes><h2>Your browser does not support frames. We recommend upgrading your
browser.</h2><br><br>
<center>Click <a href="http://server1.darkfoxdev.com:9000/sonar/api/server/versi
on" >here</a> to enter the site.</center>
</noframes>
</html>


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.078s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 24 09:21:17 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (d
efault-cli) on project prova: SonarQube <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML
4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
[ERROR] <html>
[ERROR] <head>
[ERROR] <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
[ERROR] <meta name="VERSION" content="">
[ERROR] <meta name="DATA" content="fwdnode2.registrar-servers.com (98.142.221.8)
">
[ERROR] <link href=" " rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
[ERROR] <title></title>
[ERROR] </head>
[ERROR] <frameset rows='100%, *' frameborder=no framespacing=0 border=0>
[ERROR] <frame src="http://server1.darkfoxdev.com:9000/sonar/api/server/version"
 name=mainwindow frameborder=no framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></fr
ame>
[ERROR] </frameset>
[ERROR] <noframes><h2>Your browser does not support frames. We recommend upgradi
ng your browser.</h2><br><br>
[ERROR] <center>Click <a href="http://server1.darkfoxdev.com:9000/sonar/api/serv
er/version" >here</a> to enter the site.</center>
[ERROR] </noframes>
[ERROR] </html>
[ERROR]
[ERROR] does not support Maven 3
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

**[EDIT 2]**
On the same vps I've installed sonarqube-4.5.4, as for version 5.1, when i run mvn sonar:sonar I get the same error.
Could the problem be with the sonar-maven-plugin?

Comment: Can you add -V to your mvn command-line and send the full logs please ?

Comment: Please don't cross-post your questions on multiple support channels. See http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Unable-to-run-analisys-on-SonarQube-5-1-td5034706.html

Comment: I've edited my question with the output of mvn -V sonar:sonar.
Sorry about cross-post I didn't realize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved the problem it was a configuration problem on the webhost property.
In my dns configuration I have an urlFrame record that point to my sonar address, if I set the web host property to the sonar url instead of the urlFrame one everything works fine.